# Meaning of 'wait $${!}' in docker-compose.yaml?

Tags: shell, quoting, docker, yaml

I am doing some docker with letsencrypt and nginx. In the tutorial I am following there is this command for the certbot container which allows for the sertificate to be checked for validity every 12h.

```
/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'
```

I've been doing bash for some time now, but I've never seen something like this `wait $${!}` to this day? What does `$${!}` means?

**Edit:**
The command is part of docker-compose.yaml so the full command is:

`entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"`

Comment: Is this part of a Makefile? If not, is it part of some other type of file in which `$` is a special character and where `$$` would resolve to a single `$` (which would make the shell code read `wait $!`, which make sense).  Note also that this is not `bash` (you're explicitly invoking `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`).

Comment: Yes, I've updated the original question. The command is part of a docker compose file.

Comment: See also [How can I escape a $ dollar sign in a docker compose file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619582/how-can-i-escape-a-dollar-sign-in-a-docker-compose-file)

Answer (score 6):

In a YAML file used by `docker-compose`, a single literal `$` must be written as `$$`.  The double dollar sign will be replaced with a single `$` upon running the command, which makes the shell command use `${!}` (which is the same as `$!`, i.e. the process ID of the most recently started background job).

The `$$` syntax is [documented here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution):

> You can use a `$$` (double-dollar sign) when your configuration needs a literal dollar sign. This also prevents Compose from interpolating a value, so a `$$` allows you to refer to environment variables that you don’t want processed by Compose.

This bit does not really have very much (nothing, in fact) to do with `bash`. It's just about how Compose handles the YAML document.

---

Note that the use of the background job and `wait` is totally unnecessary.  An alternative and equivalent command would have been

```
/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h; done;'
```

This is has the same effect as the original command since there's nothing really happening apart from `wait` while the background job (`sleep`) is running in that command.

Comment: Doing it as `while... & wait` has side effects which the OP may be relying on: the fact that the loop runs in a child process (may be relevant to docker where the first process ends up being a child subreaper) and has its stdin redirected to /dev/null.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I can't unfortunately say much about that other than that the shell code as such would not need the background job.

Comment: I will try your solution and post some feedback. Thing is, I am a bit new with docker, and when I saw the ```wait $${!}```  I thought that chunk has to do with bash rather than docker-compose. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- The variable `$!` contains the process ID (PID) of the process that just ran.
- `wait $!` waits until this process is finished.
- `sleep 12h &` runs `sleep 12h` in the background.

So this shell script runs sleep in the background and waits for it to finish.

Why it doesn't run sleep in the foreground and why the variable name `$!` is written so strange is not clear to me.

Comment: So, what's with the extra `$`?  I believe this is the actual question.